# API.ai don't wait for answer but don't end conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I’m building an agent on API.ai where I ask a user a question. I’m not expecting them to answer the question back to my agent. However they may wish to follow up this question later on by asking for some more information. If I ‘end the conversation’ in my intent they can’t then do something such as say ‘tell me more’ without invoking my action again from scratch (in which case all context is lost), but similarly if they don’t say anything, then (on google home at least) the question gets repeated as it's expecting a response.

Is there anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Leon has said, you could also manage the context of the user yourself (instead of relying on API.AI's Contexts) and key off the anonymous userid that you get with each request.

This way they can deep-link back to ask you a followup question, and you know "who" is returning and where the conversation last stood when you gave a reply.

Answer (score 4):

Actions are conversational experiences. Typically your app would ask a question and the user would provide a response. Once the user exits your app, the conversational context goes back to the assistant.

If you want to provide a quick way to let the user engage with your app again, then consider implementing support for deep links: https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/define-actions#define_additional_actions

Comment: Thanks for replying. I suppose in my example it was the user might ask for info about x. X has a lot of info so I just provide some of it with the option to ask for more. I think I'm gonna have to go with Prisoners approach and store the userId and an interaction time myself to manage the context in this way with my own timeout and just have a wake up intent of "tell me more" which retrieves the relevant context from a database. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you basically want is to create an intent in which what the user will say is not predictable (they may not say anything at all).

In that case , you can simply end the response with a prompt to specify it. "...Do you want to ask something more ". If user says "no" , end the conversation in a different intent. Otherwise carry on with the flow.